# How to debug "pygame.Surface' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, pygame

## Question

I'm pretty new at Python and Pygame so I figured I'd jump right it head first and work on making a little rpg style game. I keep getting the error message below. I keep checking the code and re-watching the tutorial I'm following and I can't seem to find the problem.

I'm sure it's pretty obvious but I don't see the problem. I'm pretty sure I formatted the code in this post right but I don't know.

## Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Clayton\PycharmProjects\newgame\main.py", line 42, in <module>
gameDisplay.blit(Tiles.grass(x, y))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

## Main.py

```
import pygame
from gamescripts.textures import *
# initialize PyGame
pygame.init()

# display information
# int defines number a an integer (ex1)
display_width = int(800)
display_height = int(600)
tile_size = 32

# color definitions
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
skyblue = (135, 206, 235)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

# window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption('test game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        crashed = True

    print(event)

# render graphics
     gameDisplay.fill(skyblue)

        for x in range(0, 620, tile_size):
          for y in range(0, 480, tile_size):
            gameDisplay.blit(Tiles.grass(x, y))

# draws everything to window
    pygame.display.update()

    # num entered is game fps
    clock.tick(60)
# quit PyGame
pygame.quit()
# quit python
quit()
```

## Textures.py

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


class Tiles:

    Size = 32

      def load_texture(file, Size):
      bitmap1 = pygame.image.load(file)
      bitmap2 = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap1, (Size, Size))
      surface = pygame.Surface((Size, Size), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
      surface.blit(bitmap2, (0, 0))
      return surface

grass = load_texture('graphics\\grass.png', Size)
```

Comment: Pro-tip: excessively chatty titles are not well received here, especially if they sound like begging and pleading. Keep it succinct please.

Comment: Alright, makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an instance of your `Tiles` class.

Your `Tiles` class cannot be directly blitted without creating an instance first.

```
#create a instance of `Tiles`
tile=Tiles()
tile.load_texture('graphics\\grass.png',32)
```

Implemented into your code:

```
import pygame
from gamescripts.textures import *
# initialize PyGame
pygame.init()

# display information
# int defines number a an integer (ex1)
display_width = int(800)
display_height = int(600)
tile_size = 32

# color definitions
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
skyblue = (135, 206, 235)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

# window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height), 
pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption('test game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#create an instance of your `Tile` class
tile=Tile()
tile.load_texture('graphics\\grass.png',32)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        crashed = True

    print(event)

# render graphics
     gameDisplay.fill(skyblue)

        for x in range(0, 620, tile_size):
          for y in range(0, 480, tile_size):
            #choose example coordinates for x and y
            gameDisplay.blit(tile,(x,y))

# draws everything to window
    pygame.display.update()

    # num entered is game fps
    clock.tick(60)
# quit PyGame
pygame.quit()
# quit python
quit()

import pygame

pygame.init()
```

You should change your `Tile` class as well.

```
class Tiles:
    #initialize your class
    def__init__(self):
        pass

    #ALWAYS use self as the first parameter
    def load_texture(self,file, Size):
    bitmap1 = pygame.image.load(file)
    bitmap2 = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap1, (Size, Size))
    surface = pygame.Surface((Size, Size), pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.SRCALPHA)
    surface.blit(bitmap2, (0, 0))
    return surface
```

I suggest you really take a look at the the [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) and the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

You should also look at SO if your question was already posted. For example, I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325755/typeerror-pygame-surface-object-is-not-callable?rq=1).

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I'm still having some problems with changing the Tiles class though :P

Comment: Thanks, the problems I was facing seemed to be deeper in the code. I started drawing the window using code from one tutorial and started writing code in the window from a completely different tutorial thinking they would mesh. I threw out the project and started from the beginning again and things are working much smoother now.

Comment: Hi @ClaytonAdams, if this, or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.